# What are the display specs when you play a splitscreen console game?

Tags: xbox-one, monitor, call-of-duty-black-ops-3

If I play a splitscreen console game which splits horizontally, what are the display specs for each half? Assuming that for non-split screen the specs are 1080p, 1920 * 1080 resolution, 60 fps, and 16:9 aspect ratio. Specifically, the game I am curious about is Call of Duty Black Ops 3 for Xbox One (I know it may run in a slightly lower resolution than advertised, just asume that the advertised resolution is correct).

Comment: I think its going to vary from game to game but.. is there any reason why it would not just be one of those dimensions cut in half depending on horizontal or vertical splitting?

Comment: @James well I'd assume that the aspect raitio goes to exactly 16:4.5. But idk about resolution and frames, I'm guessing they drop. IDK if their is an exact formula for that drop or if its varys based on hardware and game. The point is, I'd like to know what it is for BO3 specifically.

Comment: it's half, slightly less if there's a border. if by screen fps you mean the screen refresh rate, that'll stay the same, if you mean the game fps that'll likely reduce by a small amount as it needs to render two different perspectives even though it's the same total number of pixels.